# danger-plugin-istanbul-coverage": "^1.6.2 giving flaky results

Tags: javascript, code-coverage, istanbul, danger

I am using danger-plugin-istanbul-coverage": "^1.6.2
but its coverage results sometimes confuse me. Sometimes the results look right but sometimes, totally wrong. For example, it tells for a given file that coverage is 0 (when its 0) but in the `Total`, it says 100%

attaching the screenshot to explain this better

[image]

As you see, there is one file here that has changed and its code coverage if 0% which is right. But in the row for Total, it says "100%", which looks totally wrong. Is this library flaky? Is there a bug in it?